# Require php files with symlinks correctly

Tags: php, laravel, symlink

So I have made several different file access permissions for our company's site. Which are dev,core and essential.

To fine manage them, we set up repositories for each level of access permissions (files do not duplicate).

And I have the files in `/var/repo/dev`, `/var/repo/core`, `/var/repo/essential.files` are symlinked to `/var/www/exmaple.com/`

The framework we are using is Laravel, and it has some bootstrap stuff. The first is to require the autoload.php

The problem is the index.php is located in `/var/www/example.com/public_html/`, when it requires the autoload.php. It traces back to `/var/repo/essential` folder, which wont help it to find autoload.php.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to make it not following the symlinks (back to `/var/repo/.....`). while to the actual folder it's in?